# Como preguntar antes de cerrar una ventana

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola a todos tengo una ventana que es creado desde javascript y quisiera que al cerrar pregunte al cliente una confirmación para cerrar, he intentado con esto:

```
var xwin = window.open("/PatientForms/RenderDinamicHtml", "", 
"width=800,   
height=540,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,fullscreen=no");

$(xwin).bind("beforeunload", function () {
return confirm("Do you really want to close?");
});
```

Mi código anterior cierra la ventana antes de la confirmación.

Pudiera alguien ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
       return '¿ Quieres salir?';
};
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono de esta forma